# Is it reliable to use old computer hard disk as an external hard drive to store data?

Tags: usb, enclosure, hard-drive, sata, hdd

I have a hard drive which cannot boot windows but works for even at higher transfer rates

also its 6 years old, I found cheap enclosure SATA to USB 3.0 enclosure that works for even 100Mbps transfer rate.

I have doubt will I lose data someday in the future? since the drive is old or the enclosure circuit could damage the HDD?

Comment: If the drive is old, and it is acting weird (cannot boot Windows), it should be suspected as failing. You can run SMART tests to see if it can provide diagnostics related to its state, but you may want to consider not putting valuable data on it unless you have backups somewhere.

Comment: Why can't it boots Windows?

Comment: @DKNguyen probably the hard is too old. the laptop was hard used 18 hours per day,  I don't know the exact reason I tried fresh windows installation as well, but for data storing it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your drive is not reliable - & - It MAY last for a long time.**

The answer to your question as the term reliable is usually understood is No!.
The drive MAY last months or even years. But there is much less certainty that it will not die within months to a year than there is with say a one year old drive.

You should ALWAYS backup data which you do not wish to lose irrevocably at any moment. Using the drive as a backup or a duplicate of another drive is an acceptable use. Use for sole storage of anything should be on the basis that you are completely prepared to accept its total loss.

Keeping the drive reasonably cool may help longevity - either in a well ventilated space in a comfortable temperature room or perhaps in the air flow of a cooling fan.

**___________________________________**

**Your drive will die!**  -

All hard disks fail - typically between about 4 hours and 8 years after first use.

I've seen several examples very near the low end (on the first day of use) and have a few at about the high end of that range.

Your disk is past the end of what could be considered a reasonable lifetime. It may operate well for another six years - but or if failed at any moment you should not be at all surprised.

**Some statistics:**

Cloud storage provider Backblaze publish ongoing hard drive failure and reliability statistics for their storage array of over 100,000 drives with statistics for a range of brands. They have a number of pages providing statistics and discussion and more. [Here](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/hard-drive-test-data.html) is a good entry point to their site. They see failure rates in the 1 to about 2.5% per annum with some outliers. replacements are usually due to availability of increasingly data-dense newer drives and they are unlikely to have many drives as old as your one.